# Need to add websocket support to a single page that's running a wsgi service

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, websockets

Current setup. I have a legacy ERP system (Thoroughbred) and i then have several in house applications (CRM, WMS) and a website that interact with it via an xml server and straight ODBC connections. The CRM, WMS, and website are all python applications running the Turbogears framework (not married to this its just the first framework i used and has served me well).

The WMS system has one page that acts like a dashboard of sorts. It should number of orders waiting to be picked, when being picked, when done being picked, and waiting to be backed. From the dash board you can drill down into shipment information and "batch" shipments for picking. Its all done with AJAX and it can be running on N computers and as soon as you add two or three machines performance on the server gets crushed from all of the polled calls via ajax. I was looking at cleaning this up and optimizing it but, and correct me if i am wrong, i am really better off going with a pub/sub websockets approach.

Whats the "best" way to do this for this single page in the application without having to change my entire stack from WSGI to something that is asnc (tornado, twisted, gevent ...).

The end goal is to just rewrite the one page with the added functionality and optimizations.

My initial, inexperienced, thought was to just serve that one page for a different web server but that just seems wrong. Then i thought i could have a webservice running that is async and the page on the javascript side would establish the websockets and that would solve my problem in a "cleaner" way but then i am getting tripped up on how to handle authentication between the two servers.

TIA